# Initializing int in an array

Tags: java, arrays, module, initialization

I am writing a code for an assignment, and I want to know what this means.

The int's in the array should be initialized so that all int's at indexes of the form 0 mod 4 are - 1

What is this saying?
How do I initialize a certain value at an index?

Comment: Do you know what initialization is? Do you know what a value is? Do you know what an array index is? Those are the first questions to answer.

Comment: It means set all the values to -1, for which the index is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Go through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I getting you right, that you need to initialize elements with `-1` where index modulus by equals `0`

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i+=4) arr[i]=-1
```

Comment: I think @David Wallace has what I'm looking for, at every multiple of 0, the value at the location is -1

Comment: Nevermind, this is the actual code which is right as well. thank you both

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int[] a = new int[8];
Arrays.fill(a, -1);
```